# Calculate Running Total Using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a WPF C# Application which is accessing data through a SQL-LINQ connection and putting it on a Datagrid.  I have added a Running Pips column and have been trying to figure out how in to get this column populated correctly. I have found several methods through searching the web, but none of these are appropriate for my particular setup. Most of the time I end up in an endless loop.  I would like the Running Pips column to be cumulative and the order of the calculation to start from the earliest 'Close Time'.

```
Close Time   Profit    Running Profit
 10.09.11     $10          $10 
 10.10.11     $20          $30 
 10.11.11     $15          $45
```

Here is a summary of the code.  I hope someone can suggest how to fix this code with any relevant information needed to aid me in implementing this:

```
public void RefreshClose() {
    if (CloseTradeCollection == null) return;
    var i = 0;

    if (StaticTool.SelectedAccount == null) {
        ExistCloseTrade = false;
        CloseTradeCollection.Clear();
        return;
    }

    Account = StaticTool.SelectedAccount;

    foreach (var trade in GetClosedTradesFromDb()) {
        if (CloseTradeCollection.Count <= i) {
            ExistCloseTrade = true;
            var tradeDetails = new Trade {
                Id = trade.id,
                Ticket = trade.ticket,
                OpenTime = trade.opentime,
                CloseTime = trade.closetime,
                Symbol = trade.symbol,
                OpenPrice = trade.openprice,
                ClosePrice = trade.closeprice,
                Profit = trade.profit,
                Comment = trade.comment.Trim(),
            };

            tradeDetails.History = tradeDetails.CloseTime - tradeDetails.OpenTime;
            CloseTradeCollection.Add(tradeDetails);
        }

        else {
            var tradeDetails = CloseTradeCollection[i];
            tradeDetails.Id = trade.id;
            tradeDetails.Ticket = trade.ticket;
            tradeDetails.OpenTime = trade.opentime;
            tradeDetails.CloseTime = trade.closetime;
            tradeDetails.Symbol = trade.symbol;
            tradeDetails.OpenPrice = trade.openprice;
            tradeDetails.ClosePrice = trade.closeprice;
            tradeDetails.Profit = trade.profit;
            tradeDetails.Comment = trade.comment.Trim();
            tradeDetails.History = DateTime.Now - tradeDetails.OpenTime;

            //tradeDetails.RunningProfit = ????????

        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a local variable to keep track of running profit, making use of the fact that the assignment operation returns the value being assigned.

```
tradeDetails.RunningProfit = (runningProfit = runningProfit + trade.profit);
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code worked. I just added the following line to it: double runningProfit = 0;  That was too easy!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general idea - you should be able to adopt it to your needs:

```
class Trade {
    public DateTime CloseTime { get; set; }
    public decimal Profit { get; set; }
}

class TradeWithRunningProfit : Trade {
    public decimal RunningProfit { get; set; }
}

class Program {

    static IEnumerable<TradeWithRunningProfit> GetRunningProfits(IEnumerable<Trade> rows) {

        decimal running_profit = 0;

        return
            from row in rows
            select new TradeWithRunningProfit {
                CloseTime = row.CloseTime,
                Profit = row.Profit,
                RunningProfit = (running_profit += row.Profit)
            };

    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var rows = new[] {
            new Trade { CloseTime = new DateTime(11,10,09), Profit = 10},
            new Trade { CloseTime = new DateTime(11,10,10), Profit = 20},
            new Trade { CloseTime = new DateTime(11,10,11), Profit = 15},
        };

        foreach (var row_with_running_profit in GetRunningProfits(rows)) {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "{0}\t{1}\t{2}",
                row_with_running_profit.CloseTime,
                row_with_running_profit.Profit,
                row_with_running_profit.RunningProfit
            );
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I ran your code in the Console and see it works.  However, I am not skilled enough to modify it within my code. I was hoping this was going to be much easier to resolve.